# Close XNA game window on rectangle click

Tags: c#, xna

I'm new to XNA and I'm trying to create a simple game menu and I'm using rectangles as menu items. I have the main class which is called `Game1.cs` and a different class for a rectangle, that is supposed to close the game on click, which is called `_exitGame.cs`. So far I've got this-

In the main class I initialize a class variable:

```
_exitGame exitGame;
```

I load the texture and the rectangle:

```
exitGame = new _exitGame(Content.Load<Texture2D>("exitGame"), new Rectangle(50, 250,300,50));
```

I've created a update code for the class:

```
exitGame.Update(gameTime);
```

And I draw the rectangle:

```
exitGame.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

In my `_exitGame` class I have this:

```
class _exitGame
    {
        Texture2D texture;
        Rectangle rectangle;

        public _exitGame(Texture2D newTexture, Rectangle newRectangle)
        {
            texture = newTexture;
            rectangle = newRectangle;

        }
        public void LoadContent()
        {

        }
        public void Update(GameTime gametime)
        {
            var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
            var mousePosition = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
            var recWidth = rectangle.Width;
            var recHeight = rectangle.Height;
            if (rectangle.Contains(mousePosition))
            {
                rectangle.Width = 310;
                rectangle.Height = 60;
            }
            else
            {
                rectangle.Width = 300; 
                rectangle.Height = 50;
            }

        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle , Color.White);
        }
    }
```

So right now what I have is a rectangle that changes its size on mouse hover. Earlier I used code `this.Close();` to close the game on keyboard button click but since I can't use it in this situation I'm a bit confused how to achieve this functionality. Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: i'm sure Discosultan's answere works for you, but still consider letting exitGame extend drawableGameComponent. It will make your life easier. Take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing an XNA game can be achieved by calling [Exit() method in your Game class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.exit.aspx).

In your case, you could raise an event in your _exitGame class

```
class _exitGame
{
    public event EventHandler ExitRequested = delegate {};

    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    public _exitGame(Texture2D newTexture, Rectangle newRectangle)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        rectangle = newRectangle;

    }
    public void LoadContent()
    {

    }
    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        var mousePosition = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
        var recWidth = rectangle.Width;
        var recHeight = rectangle.Height;
        if (rectangle.Contains(mousePosition))
        {
            rectangle.Width = 310;
            rectangle.Height = 60;
            if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                ExitRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rectangle.Width = 300; 
            rectangle.Height = 50;
        }

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle , Color.White);
    }
}
```

and subscribe to that event in your Game class

```
exitGame = new _exitGame(Content.Load<Texture2D>("exitGame"), new Rectangle(50, 250,300,50));
exitGame.ExitRequested += (s, e) => Exit();
```

A couple of notes:

- In order not to always perform nullity check when raising an event, it is often convenient to use an empty delegate `public event EventHandler ExitRequested = delegate {};`
- `mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed` expression will return true as long as left mouse button is down and not only on first click. It is fine as long as you use it to exit game, but for other scenarios where the update cycle will continue running, you should store the mouse state for previous update cycle and additionally check if mouse state was NOT pressed in previous cycle and pressed in current to catch a click event.

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I don't really understand this part: exitGame.ExitRequested += (s, e) => Exit(); what does it do really?

Comment: This row is subscribing to an event with an anonymous function using lambda syntax. What that means is that whenever exitGame instance is raising the ExitRequested event, the Game class will be notified and the function is executed. `(s, e) => Exit();` is what is called an anonymous function. It's equivalent to `void (object s, EventArgs e) { Exit(); }`. Sorry, can't do nice formatting in comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing you in the right direction:

First of all, exitGame looks like a game component to me. So why don't you make it a gameComponent. Since you want to perform drawings it must be a drawableGameComponent. You can add a component to your game with `Components.Add(new MyDrawableGameComponent);`

A gameComponent hold the gmae just like your Game1 class. So now simply class `Game.Close()` to close your game.

Good luck and do some search on gamecomponents and drawableGameComponents.

Answer (score 0):

Events are generally a good way to do that. Now, since you already found a way to know when the button was clicked in your own way, we can close the game by calling the `Close` function of your `Game` object. So for this solution, you basically need a reference to `Game` or whatever you called the Game class.